# Saved search that contains vendor bill with related Purchase orders and item receipt

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to make a saved search which contain bill with full paid status and how many purchase order and item receipt under that bill
..What is the criteria for that?

Answer (score 0):

This proposed search is a record (Vendor bill) joining to a second transaction (Purchase Order) joining to a third transaction (Item Reciept), unfortunately a saved search doesn't quite support 2nd-level joins like this. See [this Prolecto post](https://blog.prolecto.com/2020/03/07/learn-netsuite-two-dot-saved-search-notation-for-distant-joins/) for information on a workaround.

However, if the **Match bill to receipt** field is set on the vendor bill at the line level, which can be defaulted on the item, then the link to the receipt from the bill can be directly referenced, reducing the join depth from 2 to 1. This is done by filtering on the "Applied to Link Type" = "Receipt Bill" & "Purchase Order". This will give give all three records in the same search, then it's a matter of grouping and sorting to get the desired information.

On the purchase order join, you might experience a [cartesian product join](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_garmany_9_sql_cross_join.htm) between the bill and p/o. I'm not certain there is a bill line to p/o line joine, it may be bill line to p/o main line.

See SuiteAnswer [26845](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26845/) and [89109](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/89109/) for examples of searches that work with bills, receipts, and purchase orders.